# Django filter query if filter parameter exists

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filters

I'm trying to create a django filter with multiple filter parameters (ex. name, age, height). However, I only want to filter by a parameter if it exists...

In my init:

```
def __init__(self, name=None, age=None, height=None):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.height = height
```

in my query:

```
Person.objects.filter(name=self.name, age=self.age, height=self.height)
```

However, the problem is since the parameters are optional in the constructor, there is a chance that the filter is looking for `None` values, which I don't want. If `name='mike'`, `age=25`, `height=None`, I only want the filter to use the `name` and `age` parameters and exclude the `height`. Something like:

```
Person.objects.filter(if self.name: name=self.name, if self.age: age=self.age, if self.height: height=self.height)
```

Is this possible? Or would I need to first check if every variable exists and have different cases for each possible filter query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db import models as dmodels
filters = dmodels.Q(age=age) & dmodels.Q(name=name)
if height:
    filters &= dmodels.Q(height=height)
Person.objects.filter(filters)
```

[see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: What if you have an **`N`** number of fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a ***generic solution***, use a [**Custom model manager**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

```
#manager.py
from django.db.models import Manager


class CustomManager(Manager):
    def custom_filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        updated_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
        return super().filter(*args, **updated_kwargs)
```

Attach this manager in your model class as,

```
#models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
    # other fields
```

Then, use this **`custom_filter(...)`** method to query, similar to the built-in **`filter()`**

```
# example usage
Person.objects.custom_filter(name=self.name, age=self.age, height=self.height)
```

**Note:** This **`custom_filter`** method will ommit all values that are **`None`**