# filter a query based on a value only if the value is not empty in django

Tags: python, django

I need to filter a query based on a variable but only if this var is not empty ... here is what I have tried :

```py
rows = Attendance.objects.filter(type= the_type if the_type != "" else '*')
```

the problem is in the part `else '*'` I have tried to remove else, but it won't work as it is required to use an else after if in the `ternary operator`, also tried `else pass` but it gives me an error.

#### Edit

I could use `if` outside of the queryset, but `I have more than one dynamic variable that I will use in the same query, so wrapping it inside an if statement won't work well`.

Comment: Check if this solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413613/django-filter-query-if-filter-parameter-exists. Creating a custom Model Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a dict with filter parameters:

```
filter_params = {}
if the_type != "":
    filter_params['type'] = the_type
rows = Attendance.objects.filter(**filter_params)
```

?